# Slider/Images out of document flow

Tags: css

I am trying to float my sidebar to the left and my slider to the right however, my images are out of the document flow.

Basically what I'm trying to do is when the user resizes the browser window, the images will shrink (which is why I am using max-width: 100%).

**View in Chrome to see the issue**

Comment: It doesnt shrink because of you have used `position: absolute` in `#slider img` css class. If you will remove `position:absoulte`, it will shrink.

Comment: @sinanakyazici If I do that the whole slider will be useless (click the 'Additional' numbers). Even if I did that, they don't float directly to the right. There must be another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `width : 100%` for your **main** class like below.

```
.main {
position: relative;
float: right;
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have edited your markup design. You have added a new content div to outside of your article div.

**EDIT**

```
#page-wrap {
max-width: 960px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
padding-bottom: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
left: 0;
top: 130px;
}

.content {
max-width: 600px;
position: absolute;
left: 360px;
top: 130px;
right: 0;
}
```

If you change your classes this way, when the browser is resized, the image will be resized.

You can look at simple demo about this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/qCQ9H/2/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We lost power over here from a storm. I'll check it again here soon.

Comment: That fits to where it needs to go however, the image does not resize when resizing the browser.

Comment: Ah. If absolute positioning is the only way, then I'll have to revert back to my old markup which is what I used before. I was hoping to use floats to contain my footer properly. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Edit approved: OP wanted the picture removed "due to copyright"